# rafthttp: failed to find member 1 in cluster 1000 -quorum -raft consensus

Tags: blockchain, quorum, peers, enode, raft

Firstly, I  have created a node in quorum private blockchain  and initiated genesis to create blockchain using geth and bootnode . Then, I run the node and it is running blockchain. Later,  I tried to peer with the existing node,then I connected  it with  few  other   nodes it is working fine.(Genesis file, networkid is same for all enodes).

After that it is showing "leader is undefined" and

other error is "rafthttp: failed to find  member 1 in cluster 1000".

and another anomaly is  while adding the existing  peer to the cluster again (just to see its ID) it has created a raft id and appeared again in cluster(actually it should show the error but created twice the enode)
[image]

by looking into above you can see two times enode, raftid 4 and 12, created( I think it is bug in geth 20.0 version but later I have updated with geth 21 version). #how to resolve it
[image]

If I tried to remove the same enode    but it is displaying blank screen and same with other raftids. # how to resolve this error

[image]

if I tried to peer with the existing node  it is showing like this  failed to find member  . # how to solve this

my command to  this for connecting to peer
PRIVATE_CONFIG=ignore geth --datadir /home/ctquorumadmindev/QuorumChain/Test-Node2 --nodiscover --verbosity 5 --networkid 786 --raft --raftport 50501 --raftjoinexisting 2 --rpc --rpcaddr 0.0.0.0 --rpcport 8501 --rpcapi admin,db,eth,debug,miner,net,shh,txpool,personal,web3,quorum,raft --emitcheckpoints --port 25501 --ws --wsaddr 0.0.0.0 --wsport 8551 --wsapi=db,eth,net,web3,txpool,miner,admin,personal,web3 --wsorigins=*

my static node is this
[image]

main node //4ce4a5764647f418076a233a30fc34fcaa8f11d091440e5553c658d43faec60edc3992e373737716d6f4865b7606129ed1d5495819696216bd716960b20a341b is running but others are not connecting to this cluster above mentioned raft cluster is depicted for this scenario. # how to solve this

some other info  that may help you:

*multiple times I created raftId and removed it

*I tried to peer with new nodes it is showing same error

#### I have tried my best to explain current scenario, if any  extra info  needed I will be available to you

Answer (score 0):

you can delete  the raft files on all nodes and restart the clustering of node, no blockchain data can be lost.